# When trying to create a dictionary from two lists, some elements are lost

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = ['2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '3', '2', '1']
list_2 = ['az', 'z', 'c', 'bo', 'o', 'bo', 'o', 'beggh', 'eggh', 'ggh', 'gh', 'h', 'akl', 'kl', 'l']
```

The number of strings inside the two lists is the same. I want to create a dictionary from the two lists, so I try:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(list_1, list_2))
```

I expect something like:

```
{
  '2' : 'az',
  '1' : 'z',
  '1' : 'c',
  ....


}
```

I also expect that the number of key-value pairs in the dictionary is the same as the number of strings in either list_1 or list_2. However, when I try to print the dictionary out, it gives:

```
{'2': 'kl', '1': 'l', '5': 'beggh', '4': 'eggh', '3': 'akl'}
```

The number of key-value pairs is only 5, which is obviously less than the number of strings in either list_1 or list_2. What has gone wrong?

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary.  You probably want a dictionary of lists if you don't want to lose data

Comment: Dictionary keys must be unique, that's part of the point of dicts.

Comment: As @user3483203 said, you can't have duplicate keys. If you need to pair up those values make a list of tuples or a list of lists.

Comment: Dictionary comprehension exists for things like this no?

Comment: Dictionary comprehension won't gracefully handle duplicate keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have a dictionary with duplicated keys, one solution would be to group values by key, here an example using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
list_1 = ['2', '1', '1', '2', '1', '2', '1', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '3', '2', '1']
list_2 = ['az', 'z', 'c', 'bo', 'o', 'bo', 'o', 'beggh', 'eggh', 'ggh', 'gh', 'h', 'akl', 'kl', 'l']

new_dict = {
    k : list(map(lambda x: x[1], v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(list_1, list_2)), key=lambda x: x[0])
}
print(new_dict)
```

[Live example](https://repl.it/repls/FreeDeliciousPriorities)

Or simply use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(list_1, list_2):
    new_dict[k].append(v)
```